# Does the order of method invocations matter in Startup.ConfigureServices?

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection

Does the order of .AddXxxxxxx method invocations matter in Startup.ConfigureServices?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IWorkService, WorkService>();

    services.AddHostedService<QueuedBackgroundService>(); 
    services.AddTransient<IQueuedBackgroundService, QueuedBackgroundService>();

    services.AddTransient<IJobService, JobService>();

    services.AddControllers();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding services to the service collection is not order dependent **by default** *(Does not include 3rd Party integration frameworks that interact with the service collection)*.

In the case of registering multiple of the same abstraction, subsequent calls to `.AddXxxxxxx` overrides the previous one when resolved as the abstraction and adds to the previous one when multiple services are resolved via `IEnumerable<IMyType>`. Services appear in the order they were registered when resolved via `IEnumerable<{SERVICE}>`.

Reference: [**Service registration methods**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-registration-methods)

You are basically adding a set of instructions to the collection.

When the provider is being built, the framework will inspect the collection for what is needed so the provider knows how to handle requests for services to be resolved.

Comment: Okay so `AddSingleton<I,T>`, `AddScoped<I,T>`, `AddTransient<I,T>` can be invoked in any order. What about `AddHostedService<T>`.

Comment: @H2ONaCl Internally `AddHostedService<T>` calls `AddSingleton<IHostedService,T>`